# Null Pointer Exception while getting response from retrofit

Tags: android, instagram

I am using Rerofit library for getting media form instagram as
[Instagram media api](https://www.instagram.com/tomcruiseofficial_/media/)

and loading  image urls in arraylist as

```
public void loadImageUrls() {

    Call<InstagramResponse> getdata = CustomApplication.getRestClient().getService().getInstagramResponse();
    getdata.enqueue(new Callback<InstagramResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<InstagramResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if (response.body().getStatus().equals("ok")) {
                int x = response.body().getItems().size();
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                    IMAGE_URLS.add(response.body().getItems().get(i).getImages().getThumbnail().getUrl());
                    IMAGE_STANDARD_URLS.add(response.body().getItems().get(i).getImages().getThumbnail().getUrl());
                    //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Image " + i + " Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(mContext, IMAGE_URLS));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Response in API", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            Log.i("eeeeeeeee:", t.toString());
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please Check Your Network Connections", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

but it gives error ok IMAGE_STANDARD_URLS.add (while getting standard urls)
but works fine for IMAGE_URLS.add (thumbnail url)

json response is

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "items": [{
        "can_delete_comments": false,
        "code": "4eb_I4L0pu",
        "location": null,
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "https:\/\/scontent-sin1-1.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-15\/s320x320\/e15\/11357325_874501389301299_1267420428_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTAxNzM3MzY1MTk0NzcwMjg5NA%3D%3D.2",
                "width": 320,
                "height": 320
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "https:\/\/scontent-sin1-1.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-15\/s150x150\/e15\/11357325_874501389301299_1267420428_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTAxNzM3MzY1MTk0NzcwMjg5NA%3D%3D.2",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "https:\/\/scontent-sin1-1.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-15\/e15\/11357325_874501389301299_1267420428_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTAxNzM3MzY1MTk0NzcwMjg5NA%3D%3D.2",
                "width": 640,
                "height": 640
            }
        },
        "can_view_comments": true,
        "comments": {
            "count": 1429,
            "data": [{
                "created_time": "1458228411",
                "text": "vorrei essere quel cane",
                "from": {
                    "username": "sassa_babba",
                    "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpt1\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/12383491_1775370549352709_39430552_a.jpg",
                    "id": "2022426329",
                    "full_name": "OBB:595\ud83d\udd10\u2764\ufe0f Ricambio.like\ud83d\ude4c\ud83c\udffb"
                },
                "id": "1208029933892225506"
            }, {
                "created_time": "1458228413",
                "text": "@_giorgiaaquadrii_",
                "from": {
                    "username": "sassa_babba",
                    "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpt1\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/12383491_1775370549352709_39430552_a.jpg",
                    "id": "2022426329",
                    "full_name": "OBB:595\ud83d\udd10\u2764\ufe0f Ricambio.like\ud83d\ude4c\ud83c\udffb"
                },
                "id": "1208029944847747556"
            }, {
                "created_time": "1458230059",
                "text": "\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\u2764 @sassa_babba  a chi lo dici",
                "from": {
                    "username": "_giorgiaaquadrii_",
                    "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-d-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/12725166_498932666944947_495489302_a.jpg",
                    "id": "2670800058",
                    "full_name": "G\u00ef\u00f8rg\u012b\u00e6\ud83d\udc96"
                },
                "id": "1208043757965888019"
            }, {
                "created_time": "1458275284",
                "text": "The sighted of the dog sea the Jupiter's sight the rippers the oceans clouds cry for rain but omen won't aloud that bee cross the no where without compass#",
                "from": {
                    "username": "kamrolzaman",
                    "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xtp1\/t51.2885-19\/10311088_284020995108189_2128683611_a.jpg",
                    "id": "1332536123",
                    "full_name": "Kamrolzaman Yusoof"
                },
                "id": "1208423132754299242"
            }]
        },
        "alt_media_url": null,
        "caption": {
            "created_time": "1435500411",
            "text": "Seriously, its been forever!!! I'm so sorry I've been gone!",
            "from": {
                "username": "tomcruiseofficial_",
                "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xta1\/t51.2885-19\/11881704_1486545434995812_1292550057_a.jpg",
                "id": "195828025",
                "full_name": "Tom Cruise"
            },
            "id": "1017376582180751688"
        },
        "link": "https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/p\/4eb_I4L0pu\/",
        "likes": {
            "count": 21469,
            "data": [{
                "username": "fariborz_shams",
                "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xat1\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/12135375_656758564467358_757413338_a.jpg",
                "id": "1377562413",
                "full_name": "Fariborz Sh"
            }, {
                "username": "simar_kaur31",
                "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xat1\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/12519204_1725998514285846_687501394_a.jpg",
                "id": "2304168545",
                "full_name": "Simarpreet \ud83d\udc9e"
            }, {
                "username": "sinakurschat",
                "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xfp1\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/12628031_1681686505423561_369144536_a.jpg",
                "id": "1682097174",
                "full_name": "sinakurschat"
            }, {
                "username": "kale_diksha",
                "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/12797808_1709699612632081_405037044_a.jpg",
                "id": "2128472803",
                "full_name": "\ud83c\udf1fDiksha kale\ud83c\udf1f"
            }]
        },
        "created_time": "1435500411",
        "user_has_liked": false,
        "type": "image",
        "id": "1017373651947702894_195828025",
        "user": {
            "username": "tomcruiseofficial_",
            "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xta1\/t51.2885-19\/11881704_1486545434995812_1292550057_a.jpg",
            "id": "195828025",
            "full_name": "Tom Cruise"
        }
    }, {
        "can_delete_comments": false,
        "code": "z1ZddUr0qs",
        "location": null,
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "https:\/\/scontent-sin1-1.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-15\/s320x320\/e15\/11008319_335099836698595_490927836_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=OTMzNzY0NDczMjYyMzk0MDI4.2",
                "width": 320,
                "height": 320
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "https:\/\/scontent-sin1-1.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-15\/s150x150\/e15\/11008319_335099836698595_490927836_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=OTMzNzY0NDczMjYyMzk0MDI4.2",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "https:\/\/scontent-sin1-1.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-15\/e15\/11008319_335099836698595_490927836_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=OTMzNzY0NDczMjYyMzk0MDI4.2",
                "width": 640,
                "height": 640
            }
        },
        "can_view_comments": true,
        "comments": {
            "count": 1005,
            "data": [{
                "created_time": "1458092427",
                "text": "@nmedina99  your husband!!!\ud83d\ude15",
                "from": {
                    "username": "sarah.medina01",
                    "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xtp1\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/12328251_1706592859620818_1377092563_a.jpg",
                    "id": "2979787255",
                    "full_name": "Sarah Medina"
                },
                "id": "1206889214074898930"
            }, {
                "created_time": "1458161986",
                "text": "@nadaodeh98 \ud83d\ude2d\ud83d\ude2d\ud83d\ude2d\ud83d\ude2d",
                "from": {
                    "username": "sobhyehmosa",
                    "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/12783832_1512530792387446_1127138415_a.jpg",
                    "id": "2989640398",
                    "full_name": "Sob7yeh\ud83c\udf38"
                },
                "id": "1207472714532473810"
            }, {
                "created_time": "1458162022",
                "text": "@sobhyehmosa \u0632\u064a \u0627\u0644\u064a \u0639\u0646\u0627 \ud83d\ude02",
                "from": {
                    "username": "nadaodeh98",
                    "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/12818921_591515934340470_1491802960_a.jpg",
                    "id": "1120968288",
                    "full_name": "Nada Odeh | \u0646\u062f\u0649\ud83c\udf93"
                },
                "id": "1207473020053965803"
            }, {
                "created_time": "1458162053",
                "text": "@nadaodeh98 \u0627\u0627\u0627\u0627\u0627\u0627\u0627\u0627\u0627\u0627 \u0646\u0633\u062e\u0647 \ud83d\ude02",
                "from": {
                    "username": "sobhyehmosa",
                    "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/12783832_1512530792387446_1127138415_a.jpg",
                    "id": "2989640398",
                    "full_name": "Sob7yeh\ud83c\udf38"
                },
                "id": "1207473283154266122"
            }]

    "more_available": true
}
```

logcat error is

```
03-18 11:47:43.745 31691-31691/com.deepak.picassogrid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at com.deepak.picassogrid.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                                        at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallback$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:86)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

03-18 11:47:45.206 31691-31691/com.deepak.picassogrid I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31691 SIG: 9

and InstagramResponse is

```
public class InstagramResponse {

private String status;
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
private Boolean moreAvailable;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * @return The status
 */
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

/**
 * @param status The status
 */
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

/**
 * @return The items
 */
public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

/**
 * @param items The items
 */
public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

/**
 * @return The moreAvailable
 */
public Boolean getMoreAvailable() {
    return moreAvailable;
}

/**
 * @param moreAvailable The more_available
 */
public void setMoreAvailable(Boolean moreAvailable) {
    this.moreAvailable = moreAvailable;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

}

and Thumbnail.java is

```
    public class Thumbnail {

private String url;
private Integer width;
private Integer height;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

/**
 * @return The width
 */
public Integer getWidth() {
    return width;
}

/**
 * @param width The width
 */
public void setWidth(Integer width) {
    this.width = width;
}

/**
 * @return The height
 */
public Integer getHeight() {
    return height;
}

/**
 * @param height The height
 */
public void setHeight(Integer height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

}

and StandardResolution.java is

```
public class StandardResolution {

private String url;
private Integer width;
private Integer height;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * @return The url
 */
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

/**
 * @param url The url
 */
public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

/**
 * @return The width
 */
public Integer getWidth() {
    return width;
}

/**
 * @param width The width
 */
public void setWidth(Integer width) {
    this.width = width;
}

/**
 * @return The height
 */
public Integer getHeight() {
    return height;
}

/**
 * @param height The height
 */
public void setHeight(Integer height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please edit your question to both include your logcat and identify which line of code the NullPointerException occurs?

Comment: it may be because Model instagramResponse is not compatible according to your json

Comment: but it works fine for thumbnail images why it is so????

Comment: No, the question here is one arraylist works fine and other gives exception???

Comment: You haven't told us where the constant `IMAGE_STANDARD_URLS` is defined. Are you sure, that is is not `null`?

Comment: Hey thanks to all, but i got why the error comes....   Is is due to my Standard Resolution in json is having underscore standard_resolution